# Jquery Change() not working on a dynamically injected element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-events

I have a dynamically generated `<div class="editable">` element with `contenteditable="true"`. I need to fire an event on changing the text inside this div.  I use `change()` and it is not working. But on the same time `blur()` is working for me. Is there any way to fire an event on `change()`?

Unfortunately I cannot use form elements like `<input>` or `<textarea>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  //ON CHNAGE
  $('.container').delegate('.editable', 'change', function (){
    alert('fire on change');
  })
  
  //ON BLUR
  $('.container').delegate('.editable', 'blur', function (){
    alert('fire on blur');
  })
});
```

```css
.editable{
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height:20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">editable</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `on()`, not `delegate()` as it's deprecated

Comment: on('keyup paste') worked! thank you @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not change event. You can use `input`, it's an event that triggers whenever the input changes.

Also use `.on` instead of `.delegate`. It is deprecated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //ON CHNAGE
  $('.container').on('input', '.editable', function() {
    console.log('fire on change');
  })

  //ON BLUR
  $('.container').on('blur', '.editable', function() {
    console.log('fire on blur');
  })
});
```

```css
.editable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">editable</div>
</div>
```

Comment: both "input" and "keyup paste" worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use keyup event instead of 'change' or 'input' as it fires an event when a key is released.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {      
  //ON KEYUP
  $('.container').on('.editable', 'keyup', function (){
    alert('fire on change');
  });
});
```

```css
.editable{
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height:20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">editable</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "input" event instead "change", like:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  //ON CHNAGE
  $('.container').delegate('.editable', 'input', function (){
    alert('fire on change');
  })
  
  //ON BLUR
  $('.container').delegate('.editable', 'blur', function (){
    alert('fire on blur');
  })
});
```

```css
.editable{
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height:20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="editable" contenteditable="true">editable</div>
</div>
```